# Setting a scheduled job on Postgres stored function

Tags: postgresql, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, stored-functions

I have created a scheduled job using `pgagent` (I have a job, schedules and steps) but when I try to run that job nothing happens with data, in other words my stored function isn't executed. In the definition tab for the step configuration I have a call for my function, `"select GET_PORTREQ_ROWS();".`

Does anybody have an idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Have you checked the statistics tab in pgadmin, in order to know if the job ran? What about the '-s' option, that sets up a log file? Is your server window or linux?

Comment: I checked statistic tab now. I have "Couldn't get a connection to the database" in output. I'm on windows. The DB that I'm trying this is local.

Comment: Could you connect directly to your database? Are you sure your database are running properly?

Comment: Yes, just tried now and it's okay. Under connection type I've selected "Local", and I've found my DB in the DB list. It doesn't ask my for any login details.

Comment: I have found this in documentation "For a SQL step, create an entry in the password file allowing a connection to the database
given in the Database field or the Connection String field.". Where is this password file?

Comment: Take a look at step 1 and 2: https://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/pgagent-configuration-on-windows/

Comment: I have two DB-s on my Postgres localhost, "chile" and "postgres". In the entry for pgpass.conf I have:
localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:xxx(password). Is this entry OK? Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I'm not sure in this case what is username. Name of DB or?

Comment: Did you read the link I sent to you? 'hostname:port:database:username:password' ... Take care with postgres: postgres is also the default administration database

Comment: Yes, I have read it, these are my entries:
localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:marko
localhost:5432:chile:postgres:marko
, but still the same error. I don't get it.

Comment: And have you tried the #2 item? If you run psql, you should not be asked the password: this validates that your config was ok. Take a look: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: I have this written in pgpass.conf:
localhost:5432:postgres:postgres:marko.
When I try in cmd with this command: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin>psql.exe -U postgres it doesn't ak me or any pass. When I try in in pgAdmin it asks me for a password.

Comment: What user are you using in pgadming? Try removing the server and re-adding in pgadming: keep your eyes on the setup, manly on user.

Comment: I explained it here in more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347634/postgres-scheduled-job-failed

Comment: @DaniloMuñoz anything?